# table() by group in R

Tags: r

Sample data:

```
a <- sample(1:4, 100, replace = T)
b <- sample(0:1, 100, replace = T)

d <- data.frame(a, b)
```

I want to achieve this output automatically for all levels of `a`:

```
table(d$b[d$a==1])
table(d$b[d$a==2])
table(d$b[d$a==3])
table(d$b[d$a==4])
```

I could do a for-loop, but that is not in the spirit of R.

```
for (i in unique(d$a)) {
print(table(d$b[d$a==i]))
}
```

Rather, I want to use one of the many list-function in R.
I tried to use `ddply` from the `plyr` package:

```
ddply(d, ~a, function(x) table(b))
```

But that is just the same as `table(d$b)` repeated four times.

How do I apply the `table()` function to each group in `a` using a list-function, preferably `ddply`?

Comment: There is no need for `plyr` (see the answer), but you were almost there: `ddply(d, ~a, function(x) table(x$b))`. `ddply` passes subset data.frames to the function and you want `b` from these subsets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `table` with multiple arguments:

```
table(d$a,d$b)

     0  1
  1 15 10
  2  6 16
  3 13 10
  4 20 10
```

Or, if you only have the data you want to tabulate in the data.frame, it will handle it for you if you pass in the data.frame:

```
table(d)
   b
a    0  1
  1 15 10
  2  6 16
  3 13 10
  4 20 10
```

Comment: In this case, `table(d)` should suffice--unless I'm missing something obvious in the question.

Comment: Sometimes one just overthinks the solution and skips the part where one checks the help file for the relevant function in question. Obviously, I have not been using `table()` to its full potential until now...

Comment: @James Forget my last comment which I deleted, I tried it again after checking for NAs and length and wonderously it worked, so it probably was a typo... I'm sorry.

Comment: @iraserd, there is also `ftable` for when more than two variables are involved and you still want a rectangular result and not a multidimensional array.